# How to update a BIM 360 project's image using POSTMAN

Tags: json, postman, multipartform-data, autodesk-bim360

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-image-PATCH/.

I have been following all the tutorials related to Projects and have been successful in creating/updating projects for BIM 360 using POSTMAN. But I am current unsure how to create or update a project's image using POSTMAN.

The `:account_id` and `:project_id` in the URL are both specified inside the Params section.
[image]

[image]

[image: output]
The output from running POSTMAN gives the error above stating required parameters are missing. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried on my side with the same API to update the project image, and it works fine. please see the body of PATCH API as follow:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I used the same Keys and I added `type` to my Body with a similar Value. It now successfully works and updates the image of a project.